# Laravel storage directory access issue

Tags: php, linux, laravel, laravel-5, server-administration

I have a problem: my data files are not available from /storage directory (Laravel's default storage directory) on real server, them return 404 missing file error. On my local server they are available and return no error. I tried recursive chmod on storage directory but that didn't fix it. Could it be accessing rights issue?

**UPD**:

Strange things gonna stranger: I can see files in `/storage/users/` directory by url, and all files from `/storage/users/November2017` are missed for me. But, here's interesting moment: when I upload file to `/storage/users/` I cannot see it by url too. File was uploaded but browser returns me 404 error when I try to access it.

Files in `/storage/users` have been created by Voyager admin panel (default files).

Comment: I think you have problem storage path. can you add the path of file you are using ?

Comment: @SagarGautam , something like this https://my-real-site.com/storage/users/November2017/image.jpg

Answer (score 0):

Just run `php artisan storage:link` from the command line to make a link in the public folder to your storage directory.

Comment: I did, same thing.

Comment: Do you have the files in the server? What the output of  `ls -al storage/users/November2017` when run it from the server?

Comment: I see files that I uploaded before, including 'image.jpg'. Files uploaded without a problem, somehow I can't see them.

Comment: make sure the public folder has `storage` as an alias. And try with or without storage  in the path: `example.com/storage/users/image.jpg` and `example.com/users/image.jpg`. Also, beware of the letters case. Your serve is case sensitive but your local might not be.

Comment: I did as you told me, it did not make any difference, please look at my updated info above.